# Write an algorithm which will evaluate Pn (x) = (N + 1)xn + N x n - 1 + ... + 2x + 1

Tags: pseudocode, polynomial-math

Write an algorithm which will evaluate:

P<sub>n</sub>(x) = (N + 1)x<sup>n</sup> + N x <sup>n - 1</sup> + ... + 2x + 1

I am trying to write pseudocode to evaluate the above. I am trying to do using a while loop and without using arrays.

So far I have something like this:

```
P:= 0       
R:= 0       
N:= 9       
SUM:=0      
WHILE (N >=0 )      
BEGIN       
R:= N MOD 10        
BEGIN       
P:= P*X         
SUM:=SUM +R     
N:= N-R     
N:= N / 10
```

But it is not evaluating correctly.
Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Where do `N MOD 10` and `N / 10` even come from? I don't see any powers of 10 in that formula.

Comment: You need exponentiation `^`, not `MOD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need something like this:

```
SUM:=0
POWER:=1
I:=0
WHILE I <= N
    SUM:=SUM+(I+1)*POWER
    POWER:=POWER*X
    I:=I+1
END WHILE
```